# What is sint32 type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

What is the `sint32` type?

I found the type in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394493%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If needed: I'm on Windows, VS2008, C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is signed 32 bit integer. In .Net it is `System.Int32` and C# alias for it is `int`.

Some of the other ones on that list you may want to know

- `sint16` becomes `System.Int16`, or `short`
- `uint16` becomes `System.UInt16`, or `ushort`
- `uint32` becomes `System.UInt32`, or `uint`

Comment: @I4V Sorry for stealing your wording, I would have just upvoted your corrected answer but you deleted it on me :)

Comment: Thank you @Scott Chamberlain

Answer (score 2):

It is a [signed integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607323%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (the third item in the list)

> > Signed integer. 2's complement integer. e.g. an 3-bit SINT represents the integral values -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3.